# SQL query for airline database

Tags: sql, postgresql

What will the SQL query be to find the details of the earliest flight based on departure from each airport??

Columns

```
flight_id, flight_no, departure, arrival, airport_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a number to each row, per airport, based on the departure time.

For example, you can do:

```
select *
from (
  select
    flight_id, flight_no, departure, arrival, airport_name,
    row_number() over(partition by airport_name order by departure) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the earliest flights then this should help:

```
select * from t where departure = (select min(departure) from t)
```

Because the departure could be the same for more than one flight this could result in more than one result row.

To get the earliest flights (same departure at each airport) you could use:

```
select t1.* from t t1
   JOIN (select airport_name, min(departure) as departure
           FROM t t2 GROUP BY airport_name, departure) x
   ON t1.airport_name = x.airport_name
      AND t1.departure = x.departure
```

You can still get more than one flight for each airport as there is no further condition which one should be shown if they have the same departure.

Comment: From each airport

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer accordingly.